# Concatenate multiple xml - .fodt files into one large one keeping the styles of each one

Tags: xml, cobol

i need write a COBOL program to merge two or more .fodt files into one large one keeping the styles/format of each one. I wrote a program that partially works. I get an output document with all the files I want to merge but they don't keep all the styles of each one. It's not a problem of writing the code but of logic on what to insert or keep to keep the styles of each document and to keep them for each of them. I'm using windows 11 and ACUCOBOL.

The program i wrote copy from office:automatic-styles from the second document onwards and pastes it right after the </office:body> of the previous document.

This is what i'm trying to do, it partially works but it doesn't keep the correct margins of each document, the margins of the last document added set the margins for every document added previously. I tried to change the style:name of every document added but it doesn't work.
Ex file1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document
<config:config-item> </config:config-item>
<office:automatic-styles>
</office:automatic-styles>
<body>
<text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 1</text:p>
</body>
</office:document>
```

Ex file2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document
<config:config-item> </config:config-item>
<office:automatic-styles>
</office:automatic-styles>
<body>
<text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 2</text:p>
</body>
</office:document>
```

Ex merged file file1 + file2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document
<config:config-item> </config:config-item>
<office:automatic-styles>
</office:automatic-styles>
<body>
<text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 1</text:p>
</body>


<office:automatic-styles>
</office:automatic-styles>
<body>
<text:p text:style-name="P1">Test 2</text:p>
</body>
</office:document>
```

Comment: For plain concatenation - are you sure that COBOL is the right tool? IF COBOL needs to start the process, maybe just do a system call of utilities that are explicit written to do concatenation/replacement instead?

Comment: @SimonSobisch Unfortunately i have to use only cobol and nothing else

Comment: @SimonSobisch Edited the original post, btw windows 11 and ACUCOBOL

Comment: That is a good start to be a good question, now the most missing thing: Your COBOL code, what did you tried so far.

Comment: @SimonSobisch I tried to do what I showed in the example, I managed to do it but I find that all documents keep the various styles except for the margins which all become like those of the last inserted document. I can't get each document to maintain its own margins. Looking at the xml file I noticed that there are "master" tags with id "pm1" or "pm2". I tried to work on these but nothing.

Comment: It seems you don't know how the XML "target" structure should look like - in this case I'd suggest to close this question and re-create another with a different problem text and different tags - "xml" doesn't match because you do have a valid XML structure, "cobol" doesn't match because you seem to know how to get to the current example result in COBOL (and it would not matter if you'd do this in "foo") - the question is really about what your office document xml _should look like_ in the end.

Comment: @SimonSobisch Ok Simon, thanks for the replies and advice.